# Redux Async Test with Webpack+karma+etc

Tags: testing, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, karma-runner, redux

I was trying to do a async action test but failed miserable :(

the test in question is this one: https://github.com/persocon/destiny-weekly/blob/test/test/actions/index.spec.jsx

[image]

I'm getting this error message:

> 1) fill in GET_OPTIONS when fetching all options is done
>        Async Actions
>        undefined is not an object (evaluating 'store.dispatch(actions.getOptions()).then')
>   /Users/persocon/Projects/destiny-weekly/test/test.bundle.js:14669:42 <- webpack:///test/actions/index.spec.jsx:49:7

and I have no clue what that means, if this was to help I'm more confuse then ever.

**UPDATE**

had to implement fetch on the action itself instead of the $.get I was using but now I get a new error pointing to my action :v even it working on the browser:

> 1) fill in GET_OPTIONS when fetching all options is done
>        Async Actions
>        Can't find variable: fetch
>   /Users/persocon/Projects/destiny-weekly/test/test.bundle.js:42473:9 <- webpack:///src/app/javascript/actions/index.jsx:32:9
>   /Users/persocon/Projects/destiny-weekly/test/test.bundle.js:15691:23 <- webpack:///~/redux-thunk/lib/index.js:12:0
>   /Users/persocon/Projects/destiny-weekly/test/test.bundle.js:14669:20 <- webpack:///test/actions/index.spec.jsx:48:19

**UPDATE 2**
Action code:

```
const setOptions = (result) => {
return {
    type: 'GET_OPTIONS',
    options: result
}
}

const getOptions = () => {


return dispatch => {
    dispatch(startLoading())
    return fetch('/api/selectActivity')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then( json => {
                dispatch(doneLoading());
                json.unshift({advisorTypeCategory: "Selecione Uma Atividade", identifier: "", disabled: "disabled"});
                dispatch(setOptions(json));
            }
        )
 }
}
```

Comment: I see a typo here: https://github.com/persocon/destiny-weekly/blob/test/test/actions/index.spec.jsx#L16

Comment: ah, never mind, that's some funky es6 auto-assign I'm not familiar with.  Otherwise, are you sure you're dispatching an async action?

Comment: hahahhaah oh, ok, yeah, the problem is on the next test after all :( the one with Nock

Comment: I guess, don't I? :( because it tries to do the fetch thing, but it saying I do not have the variable fetch ?!?! which is nonsense the app works fine and do the fetch

Comment: Post the actions code too, It looks like the error is from actions.getOptions. `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'store.dispatch(actions.getOptions()).then')` if the app works fine and the test doesn't, defs looks like an implementation detail that you may have missed in configuring the test.

Comment: yeah, it was before I changed from $.get to fetch on the action too, I did updated the post after all with the new error, let me put the action there.

Comment: updated with the action code ;o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111479/discussion-between-4m1r-and-pedro-costa-neves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya, the Async Action Creators Example is using 'fetch' which is a bit contrived, but should work in theory.  One simple solution might be to implement it with this [isomorphic fetch library](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch).  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to implement the **Isomorphic Fetch**

Because as [4m1r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2296997/4m1r) told it was a contrived function and couldn't be found.